# Saving UITextField Data (User Inputted) when the Next button calls Segue into the Next Scene

Tags: ios, uitextfield, segue

iOS6

I have 6 UITextFields in a Scene with a Next Button that Segue's into the next Scene.

The code below works great when I hit the Done button on the keyboard:

```
- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender
{
    if (sender == LocationName) {
    self.meeting.LocationName = LocationName.text;
    }

    if (sender == LocationAddress) {
    self.meeting.LocationAddress = LocationAddress.text;
    }

    if (sender == LocationCity) {
    self.meeting.LocationCity = LocationCity.text;
    }

//I have 3 more text fields after and then I persist to CoreData:

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    }

    [sender endEditing:YES];
}
```

If the user hits the Done Button on the Keyboard, the data saves fine.

However, if the User hits the Next Button on the Navigation Bar, without hitting the Done button on the keyboard first, the user Typed inside the UITextfield DOES NOT SAVE.  I would like for the user typed Data (Data that user inputted from the keyboard) in all the fields to be saved when the user hits the Next Button on the Navigation Bar to call the next scene.

I have the following code for the Next Button:

```
- (IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    [self dismissKeyboard:sender];
}
```

I know the code for nextButtonPressed is wrong.  I think I need help with identifying which UITextField called the Keyboard to be visible, and then call the dismissKeyboard with passing the Sender as a parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `UITextField` delegate method `textFieldDidEndEditing:` to know when the focus leaves a text field. This is when you should save its data. This will be called when focus moves to another text field or when the keyboard is completely dismissed.

Your implementation of `nextButtonPressed:` should simply call `becomeFirstResponder` on whatever the next text field is. That's it. By making another text field the first responder, the previous one will have its `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate called.

Update:

```
// This assumes the LocationXXX are instance variables referencing the UITextFields
- (IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    if (sender == LocationName) {
        [LocationAddress becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (sender == LocationAddress) {
        [LocationCity becomeFirstResponder];
    // add the rest as needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  dismissKeyboard: does call on the event "Did End On Exit"  When I right click on the UITextField, Sent Events - Did End On Exit is linked to dismissKeyboard.  Wouldn't that be the same thing as textFieldDidEndEditing?  Also, for "Your implementation of nextButtonPressed: should simply call becomeFirstResponder on whatever the next text field is. That's it. By making another text field the first responder, the previous one will have its textFieldDidEndEditing: delegate called."  Can you please provide a sample code?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was tied up with my exam for the couple of day.  Thank you for updating the answer.  I believe the next button you are addressing in your code is the Next button that shows up on the keyboard.  I was referring to Next button on the Navigation Bar.  The NavBar Next button calls the Next Scene.